# The post order is different for logged-in and non-logged-in users?

Tags: posts, theme-development, loop, users, login

I noticed that for some reason on my site, the post order changes depending on whether a user is logged in or not. When I am logged in as the admin, the posts display is chronological order. But when I log out, the oldest post is displayed first, then chronological order, and then the newest post is at the bottom. What is going on here?

Update: I checked my theme's functions.php file and the extras.php file (which includes extra functions) and neither of them have any filters affecting the post order.

Update: I changed my theme to Twenty Sixteen and am still having this issue. I also am on a clean install of Wordpress. Then I updated Wordpress to make sure I didn't accidently change something but I still have the issue.

Comment: You have a custom filter which is causing this behavior. Do basic debugging and you will find out which plugin is causing this, or it could be an issue within your theme

Comment: I am using a modified version of the underscores.me starter theme. Every version of this theme seems to have that same problem for me but I don't know why. Would the filter be in functions.php?

Comment: That is what you should debug. The filters should be in functions.php or any file that is used as a custom functions file

Comment: By clean, do you mean that you also have *no* plugins installed or activated. This is really a strange issue which I have never seen.

Comment: I deactivated all the plugins to see if any of them were causing the issue and it turns out none of them were, so I reactivated them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out what was causing this problem. I had a plugin installed called [Simple Posts Generator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-posts-generator/) which I used to generate 10 sample posts for testing purposes. Since I generated the articles all at the same time, the *post_date* value in the database was the same for each post, which confused Wordpress as to what post should come first.

I fixed it by going into the database and manually changing the *post_date* values so they are all different, which solved the problem. Now all my posts are sorted correctly in chronological order.

Comment: never ever never ever use query_posts. Find your bug and fix it instead :(